# Why doesn't this simple JQuery selector work in IOS?

Tags: jquery, ios

I have this very simple html:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <a href="#" id="myId-test">Click here</a>
</div>
```

and a JQuery click handler:

```
$('#myDiv > a').on("click", function (e) {
    try {
        var count = $('[id^="myId-"').length;
        alert('Count is: ' + count);
    }
    catch(error) {
        alert('Error: ' + error)
    }
});
```

So it's supposed to alert "Count is: 1", which it does just fine on my Windows desktop browser in a Chrome browser.

But on IOS it alerts *Error: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [id^="myId-"*. I have tested in both the Chrome and Safari app browsers on my IPhone 5S and iPad mini 3. Both have IOS 8.3 installed.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/863qtua9/3/).

Why doesn't this JQuery expression work in IOS?

Comment: Try targeting with a simpler selector? Maybe class based target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missed ']'. it should like this

```
var count = $('[id^="myId-"]').length;
```